# Are phrases like 'my very good friend' grammatical?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

1. Yahya is **my very good friend**.
2. Johann Diederich Ringe and Christoph Kipshoven present **their very interesting epidemiological analysis** of the vitamin D status in the German population.

The bold phrases sound awkward to me, are they grammatical?

I'd prefer the following alternatives;

1. Yahya is **a very good friend of mine**.
2. Johann Diederich Ringe and Christoph Kipshoven present **a very interesting epidemiological analysis** of the vitamin D status in the German population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are gramatically correct.